# Probability of Obtaining A Particular Sum from Successive Dice Rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you have a regular die with 6 faces numbered 1 through 6, respectively, and roll the die 4 times.  What is the probability that the sum of the 4 rolls is 14?

This problem is equivalent to asking the number of ways to partition the number 14 into 4 subsets using 6 different numbers.  Hence we can consider 'multichoosing' 4 numbers with repetition out of 6 different numbers such that $14 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$.  I suspect that this can be done using either using multinomial coefficients in some way or multisets but I am not entirely sure.  One issue is that this does not give a way for removing those cases where the four number chosen $\ne$ 14.

The total number of outcomes from rolling a die 4 times is $6^4$, so our probability will be some number divided by this.

Is this likely a problem where I should just enumerate all possible options to find my numerator?

Comment: Have a look at the [this question][1]


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68045/rolling-dice-such-that-they-add-up-to-13-is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-solve

Comment: Thank you, the generating function approach makes sense to me.  However, I am curious as to how the 'stars-and-bars' approach works.  I am familiar with the method but I do not understand how they applied it here.

Moreover, are there any obvious modifications of this problem for which the generating function method would fail?

Comment: In the linked question, Quixotic shows how to incorporate the constraint than none of the four can be greater than $6$.  His approach would need some updating if you could have more than one part greater than $6$.  But your case is the same-you can't have more than one part greater than 6

Comment: If I am understanding his answer correctly, would the total in this case be $13\choose3$?

Comment: The sum 14 can be represented by 14 stars: **************.  To break this into four summands, you put three bars between stars.  There are 13 in-between spots, so there are $\binom{13}{3}$ ways to place the bars.  The problem is that you might have more than six stars in a row without a bar between them.  That's where the trick in Quixotic's answer comes in.  To remove solutions where the first summand, $x_1,$ is greater than $6$, let $x'_1=x_1+6,$ so that $x'_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=8$ and use stars-and-bars again to count solutions.  Solutions where $x'_1\ge1$ are solutions where $x_1\ge7$.  So ...

Comment: ...subtract these.  Do the same for solutions where $x_2,$ $x_3,$ or $x_4$ is greater than $6$.  Notice that if more than one of the $x_j$ had been greater than $6$ we'd have oversubtracted, and would have to use inclusion-exclusion to compensate.  That can't happen when the sum is 14 and there are four summands.

Comment: Very nice explanation Orrick, I only just saw there was an additional comment.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using inclusion-exclusion; see [Balls In Bins With Limited Capacity](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm). Summing over the number $t$ of dice exceeding their capacity $6$ and assigning $7$ to each of them before distributing the rest of the sum, we count

$$
\sum_{t=0}^2(-1)^t\binom4t\binom{4+14-7t-1}{4-1}=\binom{17}3-4\binom{10}3+6\binom33=206
$$

different rolls that result in this sum, so the desired probability is

$$
\frac{206}{6^4}=\frac{103}{648}\approx16\%\;.
$$