# How many ways to roll n with any number of dice

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, dice

For example, if I want to roll n=6,

with 1 die it can be thrown in $$\binom {5} {0} = 1$$ way, with
2 dice $$\binom {5} {1} = 5$$ 
3 dice $$\binom {5} {2} = 10$$ 
4 dice $$\binom {5} {3} = 10$$ 
5 dice $$\binom {5} {4} = 5$$ 
6 dice $$\binom {5} {5} = 1$$ 
The sum of these is 32 - the correct answer, I believe.

I thought that the answer for any number n (where the number of dice is d) is
$$\sum_{d=1}^{d=n} \binom {n-1} {d-1}$$
It seems that this isn't working, though. For example the correct answer for n=8 is 125, but this equation gives me 128. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Kurns, what are you actually counting with ${{n-1} \choose {d-1}}$?

Comment: The number of ways the number n can be rolled with d dice.

Comment: Sure, but why can one compute it that way? What are you really counting?

Comment: I read that online... and it seems to work, to a point at least

Comment: Though $\binom{7}{0}=1$, you cannot roll an 8 with one die, and though $\binom{7}{1} = 7$ there are only 5 ways to roll an 8 with two dice.

Comment: That does make sense. Should I start over or could this method be adjusted somehow?

Comment: Look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/620640/123852)

Comment: The formula you wrote works if $n \leq 6$.  For $n > 6$, you need to exclude those cases in which one of the summands exceeds $6$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out https://math.stackexchange.com/users/123852/fabio-somenzi and N. F. Taussig! I am only left with one question: is there an easy way to exclude those cases? I am programming this so it is pretty difficult to mess around with those exponents.

Comment: It might be easier to use the recurrence for ways $W_{n,r}$ to score $n$ with $r$ dice: $$W_{n,r}=\sum_{j=1}^{6}W_{n-j,r-1}$$ since any score of $n$ with $r$ dice can be formed from a score of $n-1$ with $r-1$ dice and a "1" on the last die or a score of $n-2$ with $r-1$ dice and a "2" on the last die and so on up to a score of $n-6$ on $r-1$ dice and a "6" on the last die. The recurrence can also be simplified to $$W_{n,r}=W_{n-1,r}+W_{n-1,r-1}-W_{n-7,r-1}$$ with starting values $W_{n,1}=1$ for $n=1\ldots 6$ and $W_{n,1}=0$ otherwise and $W_{0,r}=0$. This assumes distinct dice.

Comment: Nice thinking! I actually coded this - its only challenge is that it is slow with bigger numbers because of the recursion.

Comment: Your welcome @Kurns. There is a closed form summation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366630/probability-of-obtaining-a-particular-sum-from-successive-dice-rolls), the formulation of this actually parallels the recurrence if generating functions are used. The answer in the link cites inclusion-exclusion however. I believe there are quite a few questions on MSE regarding 'balls in bins with limited capacity' so a more thorough search will likely yield you a fuller answer. On another note: the recurrence is really easy to put into a spreadsheet to form a Pascal-like-triangle :)

Comment: Sorry, that should be "you're welcome". Also you should bear in mind that $W_{n,r}$ values for any given $r$ are symmetrically distributed over $n$ values, this might save some computing power.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is surprisingly complicated. The number of ways to roll $n$ with $m$ die is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)

$$(x + x^2 + \dots + x^6)^m = x^m \left( \frac{1 - x^6}{1 - x} \right)^m.$$

This can be simplified somewhat but not substantially by applying the binomial theorem to $(1 - x^6)^m$ and $\frac{1}{(1 - x)^m}$ (here you will need the binomial theorem with negative exponents).