# What is the domain of $g(1 + x)$?

Tags: functions

$f(x)$ is a real valued function defined as

$$f(x) = 1 + x + (14x-3-8x^2)^{0.5}$$

$$g(x) = \big(f(x)\big)^{0.5}$$

What is the domain of $g(1 + x)$?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: i created f(1+x) which comes out to be 2 + x + (3 - 2x - 8x^2 )^0.5

Comment: That’s a start, but now you want $g(1+x)$, which is $\big(f(1+x)\big)^{0.5}$, so you want $$\sqrt{2+x+\sqrt{3-2x-8x^2}}\;.$$ Then you need to figure out for which values of $x$ this expression actually makes sense. First worry about the inner square root: you have to choose $x$ so that $3-2x-8x^2\ge 0$, right? Figure out which values of $x$ do that, and then worry about the outer square root.

Comment: you can put  1+x into f(x)  and  show it,but  you should consider that,when we have   square root,domain is all  these numbers,for which   equation in square root is nnnegative,so in your case,it means that -8*x^2-2*x+3  should be greater or equal to  0,and if we multiply t by -1,this equation  must be less  then  0

Comment: How i can achieve this? Since (3-2x-8x^2)^0.5 is a not a perfect square.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I will try this .

Comment: @Brian-- 3−2x−8x2 ≥0 for 0.5 < x < 0.75.

Comment: Btw, "domain theory" does not seem like an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, $$g(1+x)=\sqrt{2+x+\sqrt{3-2x-8x^2}}\;,\tag{1}$$ so the first step is to ensure that $3-2x-8x^2\ge 0$. This quadratic happens to factor: $3-2x-8x^2=(3+4x)(1-2x)$, so it’s equal to $0$ when $x=-\frac34$ and when $x=\frac12$. To see where it’s positive you can check to see where $3+4x$ and $1-2x$ have the same sign, but it’s easier to realize that the graph of $y=3-2x-8x^2$ is a parabola opening down, so it lies above the $x$-axis between the roots $-\frac34$ and $\frac12$. Thus, $3-2x-8x^2\ge 0$ when $-\frac34\le x\le\frac12$. (You must have made a sign error in the calculation in your comment.)

Okay, now we know that the domain is **at most** the interval $\left[-\frac34,\frac12\right]$, but there might be values of $x$ in that interval that make 
$$2+x+\sqrt{3-2x-8x^2}\tag{2}$$ negative. Are there?

At $x=-\frac34$, $(2)$ is equal to $2-\frac34=\frac54$, which is certainly not negative. As $x$ increases from $-\frac34$ to $\frac12$, $2+x$ also increases, so it won’t be a problem: it will always be at least $\frac54$. What about $\sqrt{3-2x-8x^2}$? On the interval $\left[-\frac34,\frac12\right]$ it’s always at least $0$, so it won’t be a problem either, and we can be sure that $(2)$ is always at least $\frac54$ when $-\frac34\le x\le\frac12$. In particular, it won’t be negative, so we can take its square root. Thus, the domain of $g(1+x)$ is the whole interval $\left[-\frac34,\frac12\right]$.

Comment: Thanks Brian.Thank you so much

Comment: M.Scott I need your help.I will be true to you.I have a question and i posted on this site.but later some guy found that question somewhere, so i deleted my question.I read your answer on this question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65934/how-many-numbers-between-100-and-900-have-sum-of-their-digits-equal-to-15 .So i thought you can better explain me this question. **How many seven-digit numbers divisible by 11 have the sum of their digits equal to 59?** I am really sorry as i am asking you question in a comment.I will very thankful to you if you can explain me.

Comment: @vikiiii: I didn’t have time to think about this today, but I will take a look.

Comment: M.Scott Thanks so much.Any time whenever you are free.

Comment: @vikiiii: The maximum possible digit sum is $7\cdot9=63$, and $63-59=4$, so at least $7-4=3$ of the digits must be $9$. We can have $3$ $9$’s and $4$ $8$’s; $4$ $9$’s, $2$ $8$’s, and a $7$; $5$ $9$’s and $2$ $7$’s; $5$ $9$’s, an $8$, and a $6$; of $6$ $9$’s and a $5$; no other combinations add up to $59$. Now you just have to determine which of these five combinations can be arranged to make multiples of $11$. For example with $3$ $9$’s and $4$ $8$’s, we can make $9898988$, $9898889$, $9888989$, and $8898989$, all of which are multiples of $11$. (cont.)

Comment: @vikiiii: (cont.) Do you know the test for divisibility by $11$? It’s quite helpful here. Take the sum of the digits in the odd-numbered position, and subtract from that the sum of the digits in the even-numbered positions. In the four numbers that I just listed, that’s $$(9+9+9+8)-(8+8+8)=11\;.$$ The original number is divisible by $11$ if and only if this alternating digit sum is divisible by $11$, as it certainly is here. (I’ll give it a bit more thought to see if I can come up with a less tedious approach.)

Comment: @vikiiii: Why don’t you go ahead and submit it as a question, and I’ll write up a decent answer. It really is a bit different from the usual questions of this type. If you do, give me a ping to be sure that I see it.

Comment: M.Scott I have posted my question on this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126270/how-many-seven-digit-numbers-satisfy-the-following-conditions